# Как в пагинации woocommerce убрать стрелку, а поставить свою BG?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

У пагинации в wocommerce есть стрелка, нажимая на которую, происходит перелистывание на последнюю страницу. Эта стрелка прописана символом по дефолту в HTML этой стрелки. По шаблону мне нужно вставить свою стрелку background`ом. Подскажите, как убрать эту стрелку в HTML woocommerce, которая стоит по стандарту.
[image: Сейчас стрелка, которая стоит по дефолту]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте таким образом:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_pagination_args', function ( $args ) {
    $args['prev_text'] = '<i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-left"></i>'; // ваша стрелка
    $args['next_text'] = '<i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>'; // ваша стрелка

    return $args;
} );
```

Естественно вы можете добавить какой-то свой HTML элемент, на который и повесите свой бекграунд при помощи css.

Comment: Заработало! Очень благодарен вам сегодня! Выручаете :)

Comment: А можете подсказать, как в функции `woocommerce_result_count();` поменять текст с "Отображение 1–9 из 11" на "Показано: 9 из 12 товаров"?

Comment: Можете скопировать файл woocommerce/templates/loop/result-count.php в свою тему и там отредактировать как вам будет нужно.

Comment: Благодарю! Просто впервые с woocommerce работаю, приходится познавать :)

Comment: Подскажите, скопировал "result-count.php" в свою тему. Точно так же делал ранее с 2 файлами. При изменении в свой теме "result-count.php" - ничего не меняется. Действует только файл, который находиться в самом плагине woocommerce. Как подключить мой файл, который я скопировал?

Comment: А вы у себя в теме положили его в папку templates/loop или просто закинули в папку templates? Я почему спрашиваю, если вы посмотрите на саму функцию, то темплейт берется именно из папки loop https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/woocommerce_result_count/

Comment: Всё, большущее спасибо! :)